# where is tensorflow probability calculated?

Tags: android, tensorflow, machine-learning, detection, tensorflow-datasets

I am using tf_detect. In that my machine learning detects the items and displays the probability of image being that object in actual life. but the probability is given in decimal points ie. 0.01(min) to 1(max). I want to change it to 1(min) and 100(max) ie. multiply what it is currently showing by hundred. but i cant seem to find where it is calculated.
please help , thank you for your suggestions

```
/*

* Copyright 2016 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.

*

* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");

* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.

* You may obtain a copy of the License at

*

*       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

*

* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software

* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,

* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.

* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and

* limitations under the License.

*/


package org.tensorflow.demo;


import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;

import android.graphics.Canvas;

import android.graphics.Color;

import android.graphics.Matrix;

import android.graphics.Paint;

import android.graphics.Paint.Style;

import android.graphics.RectF;

import android.graphics.Typeface;

import android.media.ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener;

import android.os.SystemClock;

import android.util.Size;

import android.util.TypedValue;

import android.view.Display;

import android.view.Surface;

import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.LinkedList;

import java.util.List;

import java.util.Vector;

import org.tensorflow.demo.OverlayView.DrawCallback;

import org.tensorflow.demo.env.BorderedText;

import org.tensorflow.demo.env.ImageUtils;

import org.tensorflow.demo.env.Logger;

import org.tensorflow.demo.tracking.MultiBoxTracker;

import org.tensorflow.demo.R; // Explicit import needed for internal Google builds.


/**

* An activity that uses a TensorFlowMultiBoxDetector and ObjectTracker to detect and then track

* objects.

*/

public class DetectorActivity extends CameraActivity implements OnImageAvailableListener {

private static final Logger LOGGER = new Logger();


// Configuration values for the prepackaged multibox model.

private static final int MB_INPUT_SIZE = 224;

private static final int MB_IMAGE_MEAN = 128;

private static final float MB_IMAGE_STD = 128;

private static final String MB_INPUT_NAME = "ResizeBilinear";

private static final String MB_OUTPUT_LOCATIONS_NAME = "output_locations/Reshape";

private static final String MB_OUTPUT_SCORES_NAME = "output_scores/Reshape";

private static final String MB_MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/multibox_model.pb";

private static final String MB_LOCATION_FILE =

    "file:///android_asset/multibox_location_priors.txt";


private static final int TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE = 300;

private static final String TF_OD_API_MODEL_FILE =

    "file:///android_asset/ssd_mobilenet_v1_android_export.pb";

private static final String TF_OD_API_LABELS_FILE = "file:///android_asset/coco_labels_list.txt";


// Configuration values for tiny-yolo-voc. Note that the graph is not included with TensorFlow and

// must be manually placed in the assets/ directory by the user.

// Graphs and models downloaded from http://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/ may be converted e.g. via

// DarkFlow (https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow). Sample command:

// ./flow --model cfg/tiny-yolo-voc.cfg --load bin/tiny-yolo-voc.weights --savepb --verbalise

private static final String YOLO_MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/graph-tiny-yolo-voc.pb";

private static final int YOLO_INPUT_SIZE = 416;

private static final String YOLO_INPUT_NAME = "input";

private static final String YOLO_OUTPUT_NAMES = "output";

private static final int YOLO_BLOCK_SIZE = 32;


// Which detection model to use: by default uses Tensorflow Object Detection API frozen

// checkpoints.  Optionally use legacy Multibox (trained using an older version of the API)

// or YOLO.

private enum DetectorMode {

  TF_OD_API, MULTIBOX, YOLO;

}

private static final DetectorMode MODE = DetectorMode.TF_OD_API;


// Minimum detection confidence to track a detection.

private static final float MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE_TF_OD_API = 0.6f;

private static final float MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE_MULTIBOX = 0.1f;

private static final float MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE_YOLO = 0.25f;


private static final boolean MAINTAIN_ASPECT = MODE == DetectorMode.YOLO;


private static final Size DESIRED_PREVIEW_SIZE = new Size(640, 480);


private static final boolean SAVE_PREVIEW_BITMAP = false;

private static final float TEXT_SIZE_DIP = 10;


private Integer sensorOrientation;


private Classifier detector;


private long lastProcessingTimeMs;

private Bitmap rgbFrameBitmap = null;

private Bitmap croppedBitmap = null;

private Bitmap cropCopyBitmap = null;


private boolean computingDetection = false;


private long timestamp = 0;


private Matrix frameToCropTransform;

private Matrix cropToFrameTransform;


private MultiBoxTracker tracker;


private byte[] luminanceCopy;


private BorderedText borderedText;

@Override

public void onPreviewSizeChosen(final Size size, final int rotation) {

  final float textSizePx =

      TypedValue.applyDimension(

          TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, TEXT_SIZE_DIP, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

  borderedText = new BorderedText(textSizePx);

  borderedText.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);


  tracker = new MultiBoxTracker(this);


  int cropSize = TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE;

  if (MODE == DetectorMode.YOLO) {

    detector =

        TensorFlowYoloDetector.create(

            getAssets(),

            YOLO_MODEL_FILE,

            YOLO_INPUT_SIZE,

            YOLO_INPUT_NAME,

            YOLO_OUTPUT_NAMES,

            YOLO_BLOCK_SIZE);

    cropSize = YOLO_INPUT_SIZE;

  } else if (MODE == DetectorMode.MULTIBOX) {

    detector =

        TensorFlowMultiBoxDetector.create(

            getAssets(),

            MB_MODEL_FILE,

            MB_LOCATION_FILE,

            MB_IMAGE_MEAN,

            MB_IMAGE_STD,

            MB_INPUT_NAME,

            MB_OUTPUT_LOCATIONS_NAME,

            MB_OUTPUT_SCORES_NAME);

    cropSize = MB_INPUT_SIZE;

  } else {

    try {

      detector = TensorFlowObjectDetectionAPIModel.create(

          getAssets(), TF_OD_API_MODEL_FILE, TF_OD_API_LABELS_FILE, TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE);

      cropSize = TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE;

    } catch (final IOException e) {

      LOGGER.e("Exception initializing classifier!", e);

      Toast toast =

          Toast.makeText(

              getApplicationContext(), "Classifier could not be initialized", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

      toast.show();

      finish();

    }

  }


  previewWidth = size.getWidth();

  previewHeight = size.getHeight();


  sensorOrientation = rotation - getScreenOrientation();

  LOGGER.i("Camera orientation relative to screen canvas: %d", sensorOrientation);


  LOGGER.i("Initializing at size %dx%d", previewWidth, previewHeight);

  rgbFrameBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(previewWidth, previewHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);

  croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cropSize, cropSize, Config.ARGB_8888);


  frameToCropTransform =

      ImageUtils.getTransformationMatrix(

          previewWidth, previewHeight,

          cropSize, cropSize,

          sensorOrientation, MAINTAIN_ASPECT);


  cropToFrameTransform = new Matrix();

  frameToCropTransform.invert(cropToFrameTransform);


  trackingOverlay = (OverlayView) findViewById(R.id.tracking_overlay);

  trackingOverlay.addCallback(

      new DrawCallback() {

        @Override

        public void drawCallback(final Canvas canvas) {

          tracker.draw(canvas);

          if (isDebug()) {

            tracker.drawDebug(canvas);

          }

        }

      });


  addCallback(

      new DrawCallback() {

        @Override

        public void drawCallback(final Canvas canvas) {

          if (!isDebug()) {

            return;

          }

          final Bitmap copy = cropCopyBitmap;

          if (copy == null) {

            return;

          }


          final int backgroundColor = Color.argb(100, 0, 0, 0);

          canvas.drawColor(backgroundColor);


          final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

          final float scaleFactor = 2;

          matrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);

          matrix.postTranslate(

              canvas.getWidth() - copy.getWidth() * scaleFactor,

              canvas.getHeight() - copy.getHeight() * scaleFactor);

          canvas.drawBitmap(copy, matrix, new Paint());


          final Vector<String> lines = new Vector<String>();

          if (detector != null) {

            final String statString = detector.getStatString();

            final String[] statLines = statString.split("\n");

            for (final String line : statLines) {

              lines.add(line);

            }

          }

          lines.add("");

          lines.add("Frame: " + previewWidth + "x" + previewHeight);

          lines.add("Crop: " + copy.getWidth() + "x" + copy.getHeight());

          lines.add("View: " + canvas.getWidth() + "x" + canvas.getHeight());

          lines.add("Rotation: " + sensorOrientation);

          lines.add("Inference time: " + lastProcessingTimeMs + "ms");


          borderedText.drawLines(canvas, 10, canvas.getHeight() - 10, lines);

        }

      });

}


OverlayView trackingOverlay;


@Override

protected void processImage() {

  ++timestamp;

  final long currTimestamp = timestamp;

  byte[] originalLuminance = getLuminance();

  tracker.onFrame(

      previewWidth,

      previewHeight,

      getLuminanceStride(),

      sensorOrientation,

      originalLuminance,

      timestamp);

  trackingOverlay.postInvalidate();


  // No mutex needed as this method is not reentrant.

  if (computingDetection) {

    readyForNextImage();

    return;

  }

  computingDetection = true;

  LOGGER.i("Preparing image " + currTimestamp + " for detection in bg thread.");


  rgbFrameBitmap.setPixels(getRgbBytes(), 0, previewWidth, 0, 0, previewWidth, previewHeight);


  if (luminanceCopy == null) {

    luminanceCopy = new byte[originalLuminance.length];

  }

  System.arraycopy(originalLuminance, 0, luminanceCopy, 0, originalLuminance.length);

  readyForNextImage();


  final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(croppedBitmap);

  canvas.drawBitmap(rgbFrameBitmap, frameToCropTransform, null);

  // For examining the actual TF input.

  if (SAVE_PREVIEW_BITMAP) {

    ImageUtils.saveBitmap(croppedBitmap);

  }


  runInBackground(

      new Runnable() {

        @Override

        public void run() {

          LOGGER.i("Running detection on image " + currTimestamp);

          final long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

          final List<Classifier.Recognition> results = detector.recognizeImage(croppedBitmap);

          lastProcessingTimeMs = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;


          cropCopyBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(croppedBitmap);

          final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(cropCopyBitmap);

          final Paint paint = new Paint();

          paint.setColor(Color.RED);

          paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

          paint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);


          float minimumConfidence = MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE_TF_OD_API;

          switch (MODE) {

            case TF_OD_API:

              minimumConfidence = MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE_TF_OD_API;

              break;

            case MULTIBOX:

              minimumConfidence = MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE_MULTIBOX;

              break;

            case YOLO:

              minimumConfidence = MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE_YOLO;

              break;

          }


          final List<Classifier.Recognition> mappedRecognitions =

              new LinkedList<Classifier.Recognition>();


          for (final Classifier.Recognition result : results) {

            final RectF location = result.getLocation();

            if (location != null && result.getConfidence() >= minimumConfidence) {

              canvas.drawRect(location, paint);


              cropToFrameTransform.mapRect(location);

              result.setLocation(location);

              mappedRecognitions.add(result);

            }

          }


          tracker.trackResults(mappedRecognitions, luminanceCopy, currTimestamp);

          trackingOverlay.postInvalidate();


          requestRender();

          computingDetection = false;

        }

      });

}


@Override

protected int getLayoutId() {

  return R.layout.camera_connection_fragment_tracking;

}


@Override

protected Size getDesiredPreviewFrameSize() {

  return DESIRED_PREVIEW_SIZE;

}


@Override

public void onSetDebug(final boolean debug) {

  detector.enableStatLogging(debug);

}

}
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using as a code, not as a document.

Comment: And also how can I get the height and width of the rectangle which hovers over detected object?